# revaluing variables in R

Tags: r

I have 500 entries in a column and I want to change them with the following function:

```
data[data$HouseStyle,"HouseStyle"]<-revalue(data$HouseStyle,c("2Story"="1.5Sto"))
```

I get as an ouput the original 500 entries PLUS the 500 revalued entries(of course I only want the revalued ones). What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is `revalue` defined? If I understand correctly what it does then you’d just write something like `data$HouseStyle = revalue(data$HouseStyle, …)`. Your subsetting on the left-hand side is suspect.

Comment: Thank you, I was just a little bit confused

Answer (score 1):

As Konrad mentioned in his comment :

```
data$HouseStyle <-revalue(data$HouseStyle,c("2Story"="1.5Sto"))
```